# Spark SQL builder - JAVA API

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently developing an aplication for enterprise metadata management. I have a requirement to translate metadata stored in relational database into a bunch of Spark SQL. The app is written in Java so I am working if there is a Java based API available to build Spark SQL (properly syntax’d) and then stringify it. I dont have to run the query. The requirement is to build the query and deliver it to a seperate execution engine.

Can anyone suggest if such API is available? I researched on GitHub but couldn’t find one.

Comment: You want a StringBuilder or a Dataframe operation creator?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since I don't want to run Spark SQL I think I do want something like a String Builder for Spark SQL. I need anything that can create a spark sql in a cleaner way and makes sure that created query is syntactically correct.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what type of queries you are trying to create. SparkSQL / HiveQL syntax is pretty broad.

Comment: I have to create Spark SQL mostly SELECT statements with joins, aggregate functions, etc. I have to create queries dynamically based on some input. Once the queries are created they will be delivered to another system (execution engine) which is going to run those queries.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that asking for libraries is off topic for Stackoverflow, so it'd help if you could edit you question to show what data you have that's generating the statements and any attempts you've made to create the simplest sql queries